# LALR grammar for string concatenation

Tags: parsing, grammar, lalr, shift-reduce-conflict

I've been trying to parse concatenated strings such that expressions can also be concatenated to form the string. That is,

```
"No, " + 4*(6+5)/(8-4) + " is not equal to " + 75*1.3 + "."
```

The above should be parsed correctly. The problem is that `+` leads to shift-reduce conflicts. I've been using the following grammar;

```
<S> ::= <A> '+' <S>
      | <A>
<A> ::= <E>
       |QUOT
<E> ::= <T> '+' <E>
      | <T> '-' <E>
      | <T>
<T> ::= <F> '*' <T>
      | <F> '/' <T>
      | <F>
<F> ::= NUM
      | '(' <E> ')'
```

I've haven't had any success in trying to find a grammar where `+` does not cause a shift-reduce conflict. I'm hoping that there is a way to make this grammar LALR, and I'll really appreciate some help in trying to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If:

1. You don't care about how either `+` operator (addition or concatenation) associates; and
2. You don't need to be able to use parentheses around string expressions,

then there is a solution. I regard it more as an intellectual exercise than a practical solution, partly because the above requirements are highly restrictive, and partly because I don't think you should use the same operator with two different precedences. (In fact, I'm not a big supporter of using `+` for concatenation. It's different enough that it deserves its own symbol.)

The following solution works pretty hard to make sure that string expressions are distinguishable from arithmetic expressions, which requires that string expressions cannot start with a `(`. In order to avoid premature reduction of concatenation, it makes the concatenation version of `+` associate to the right, while the addition version associates to the left as normal.

```
S : E '+' A
  | E
  | A
  ;

A : QUOT '+' S
  | QUOT
  ;

E : E '+' T
  | E '-' T
  | T
  ;

T : T '*' F
  | T '/' F
  | F
  ;

F : NUM
  | '(' E ')'
  ;
```

Comment: Yes, from a practical standpoint I was already considering using `.` or empty strings. But I was curious if something in the grammar could be changed to allow it to be parsed with an LALR parser. This solution is excellent, but I'm still curious; do languages like Javascript which use a similar kind of string concatenation restrict themselves to use a similar LALR grammar or do they use something else? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Rikonator: Javascript (and, as far as I know, all other languages which use `+` for concatenation) uses the same precedence for `+` regardless of type. Consequently, `"a" + 2+2 + "b"` will evaluate to `"a22b"` and not `"a4b"`. Particular implementations may or may not use an LALR(1) parser, but such a parser is relatively easy to construct. Trying to make the same operator have two different binding precedences is, as I said, difficult and probably unwise. `awk` style concatenation (no operator) is probably also unwise. See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.utils.bugs/17162.